# Kafka Container comes up with a different name like net_kafka0.example.com_run_1

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric

I have set up a kafka based ordering service for my Hyperledger Fabric network consisting of 2 orderers, 4 Kafka brockers and 3 zookeeper nodes.

When I start my Fabric network(using `docker-compose -f ... up -d`) everything goes fine without any errors, but the problem is I dont see any logs in the kafka containers during the transactions.

The kafka containers update the log only when it starts and the channel is created.

Someone suggested me to run kafka containers individually(using `docker-compose -f ... run kafka0.example.com`) in different terminal windows, then start the fabric network. But then, the kafka containers come up with a name like `net_kafka0.example.com_run_1, net_kafka1.example.com,...` The zookeeper containers come up with the same name as defined in the config file(i have used `docker-compose -f ... up -d zookeeper0.example.com zookeeper1.example.com zookeeper2.example.com`).

But my fabric network expect the name as kafka0.example.com and hence failures are reported by the fabric orderers.

The kafka and zookeeper docker file:

```
version: '2'
networks:
  basic:

services:
  zookeeper0.example.com:
    container_name: zookeeper0.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper
    environment:
      - ZOO_MY_ID=0
      - ZOO_SERVERS=server.1=zookeeper0.example.com:2888:3888 server.2=zookeeper1.example.com:2888:3888 server.3=zookeeper2.example.com:2888:3888
    restart: always
    networks:
      - basic 
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
      - 2888:2888
      - 3888:3888

  kafka0.example.com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-kafka
    container_name: kafka0.example.com
    environment:
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=0
      #- KAFKA_SOCKET_REQUEST_MAX_BYTES=104857600 # 100 * 1024 * 1024 B
      - KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES=103809024 # 99 * 1024 * 1024 B
      - KAFKA_REPLICA_FETCH_MAX_BYTES=103809024 # 99 * 1024 * 1024 B
      - KAFKA_UNCLEAN_LEADER_ELECTION_ENABLE=false
      - KAFKA_MIN_INSYNC_REPLICAS=2
      - KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR=3
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper0.example.com:2181,zookeeper1.example.com:2181,zookeeper2.example.com:2181
      #- KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MS = 6000
      #- KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS = 6000
    networks:
      - basic         
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper0.example.com
      - zookeeper1.example.com
      - zookeeper2.example.com
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
      - 9093:9093
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would not recommend starting Kafka containers individually, that should not make a difference if you are running all of them in one machine.

Second of all, if you can submit transactions, but do not see them in the Kafka logs it might be that you are running orderer type solo. Check your docker-compose file and make sure you use "CONFIGTX_ORDERER_ORDERERTYPE=kafka".

Comment: I have used OrdererType: kafka in the Configtx.yaml file. 
Also when I start kafka containers individually it comes up with different name. Please go through my question.

Comment: Could you also provide orderer docker composer files and orderer, kafka, zookeeper  logs?